# How can I get a count of the total number of series in a chart in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I created a chart in a sheet,and now I want set the format of the series using the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ***number of series***; i++)
{
    set_Series_Format(Excelbook, Chart_ScatterSmooth.SeriesCollection(i));
}
```

I have to get the count of  total number of series in the chart , but till now I haven't got any solution.

Comment: What is the type of the variable you are trying to iterate?

Answer (score 0):

I find that once I have added a `Series` I can query the `SeriesCollection.Count` property:

```
 Excel.SeriesCollection  sc = myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection();
 int SeriesCount = sc.Count;
```

Curiously it reports `0`before I add a `Series` and `2` after. So maybe the 'collection' just isn't one with only the default `Series`. The [`SeriesCollection()` and its docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.seriescollection.aspx)
 are suggesting something like this, but I'm really not sure:

> Gets either a single series (a T:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series
>   object) or a collection of all the series (a
>   T:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection collection) in the
>   chart or chart group

Answer (score 0):

Question is old but someone might appreciate the answer.

```
// Get the chart object
Excel.ChartObject xlChartObject = xlSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1");
// Get the chart from the chart object
Excel.Chart xlChart = xlChartObject.Chart;
// Get the full series collection from the chart
Excel.FullSeriesCollection fullSeriesCollection = xlChart.FullSeriesCollection();

// Returns the count of series from the chart
int SeriesCount = fullSeriesCollection.Count;
```

**fullSeriesCollection.Count** will return of the series in the chart **xlChart**.
The documentation can be found here [FullSeriesCollection Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.fullseriescollection)

One of the good things about **FullSeriesCollection()** is that it contains an enumerator which will allow you to loop over the series:

```
foreach (Excel.Series xlSeries in xlChart.FullSeriesCollection())
{
    xlSeries.MarkerStyle = Excel.XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleCircle;
}
```

Hope this helps.